# AngularJS/Router minimize API calls

Tags: angularjs

Would it be possible to make all the API calls once when the user lands on the page from the url and store all the data as cache and then use the cache to render the state changes from Angular router?

I can see it being implemented by a service that populates the rootscope but would this method be recommended instead of calling the API multiple times?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? I think you should only make a request when you actually need it - Less request make your page render faster and reduce unnecessary calls to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use $http and set cache to true.
Should be enough for your needs.

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The default cache value can be set by updating the $http.defaults.cache property or the $httpProvider.defaults.cache
>   property.
>
> When caching is enabled, $http stores the response from the server
>   using the relevant cache object. The next time the same request is
>   made, the response is returned from the cache without sending a
>   request to the server.
>
> Take note that:
>
> Only GET and JSONP requests are cached. The cache key is the request
>   URL including search parameters; headers are not considered. Cached
>   responses are returned asynchronously, in the same way as responses
>   from the server. If multiple identical requests are made using the
>   same cache, which is not yet populated, one request will be made to
>   the server and remaining requests will return the same response. A
>   cache-control header on the response does not affect if or how
>   responses are cached.